# change consensus of substrate

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, consensus

I want to change my substrate chain consensus but I don't know how to set the new consensus in substrate.

I want to set dops consensus for my substrate chain also please guide my for implement dpos in substrate.

**How can i implement dpos? How can I set custom consensus as default in substrate ?**

Answer (score 3):

From a parachain's perspective you do not need to change the consensus.

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/kilt-protocol/the-continuing-evolution-of-kilt-protocol-limited-delegated-proof-of-stake-640403427c48) blog article by Kilt, a team that has successfully implemented limited delegated proof of stake.

Note that in [their runtime](https://github.com/KILTprotocol/kilt-node/blob/8fe2c4de746bfee57154e0b970b39f860c75b769/runtimes/spiritnet/src/lib.rs#L909-L911) they use Aura and a [custom staking pallet](https://github.com/KILTprotocol/kilt-node/tree/develop/pallets/parachain-staking).

There are other chains in the ecosystem who are doing DPoS as well.

I recommend you start by reviewing their implementations.