# Substrate change node template from PoA to PoS

Tags: substrate-node-template, staking, babe

Is there any documentation on how to change Substrate from PoA to PoS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following posts may help:

- [How to upgrade consensus engine of a live chain from PoA to PoS?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/996/how-to-upgrade-consensus-engine-of-a-live-chain-from-poa-to-pos/1038#1038)
- [How to change consensus engine from PoA to PoS?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/368/how-to-change-consensus-engine-from-poa-to-pos/389#389)

Also, you may want to consider the parachain route:

- [change consensus of substrate](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5840/change-consensus-of-substrate/5849#5849)

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated the POS in fresh node-template on **polkadot-v1.0.0**

Here you can find the POS(proof-of-stake) node-template with babe: https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/POA-to-POS

Thanks!