# Switching from Aura to Babe - 'Current state of blockchain has invalid authorities set'

Tags: babe, genesis, epoch

I'm attempting to switch a node from using Aura to Babe by copying the usage of Babe in some public chains.

However when I run multiple nodes together I get the error:

```
Unable to fetch auxiliary data for block 0x3d9c9122e3c7355cf0c21b8dc75cb858e4d03ce4a7f88f7639b59f6cde40b86d: Current state of blockchain has invalid authorities set
```

I've also noticed that `EpochStart` is `[0, 0]`. This is authorities:

```
[
  [
    0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
    1
  ]
  [
    0x8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48
    1
  ]
  [
    0x90b5ab205c6974c9ea841be688864633dc9ca8a357843eeacf2314649965fe22
    1
  ]
]
```

Genesis config sets the authorities with

```
                vec![
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"),
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Bob"),
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Charlie"),
                ]
```

The full changeset PR is https://github.com/digicatapult/dscp-node/pull/130/files

What could we causing this issue as the authorities appear to be valid?

Comment: Please review this: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/substrate-change-node-template-from-poa-to-pos