# Switching from `Aura` to `Babe` consensus causes error "Incomplete block import pipeline" on genesis block

Tags: consensus, grandpa, babe

I am trying to switch from `Aura` to `Babe` consensus. After successful building and node start I am getting an error "Block import error: Incomplete block import pipeline.". This happens with genesis block. For finalization I use granpa consensus. Any ideas what did I  wrong?

Version of substrate is `monthly-2022-09`

Comment: Without any examples, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Use this post as a guideline: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/substrate-change-node-template-from-poa-to-pos